Can I create a single instance of a class using a higher-kinded type as a parameter?
It's difficult to even formulate the question concisely yet descriptive enough. I want to create a Semigroup instance for Sets with intersection operation. So I'm trying to communicate to a compiler that I want one instance for all sets regardless of their type parameter, but combine should only work on sets of the same element type.
trait Semigroup[A] {
  def combine(x: A, y: A): A
}

object Semigroup {
  implicit def setIntersectionSG: Semigroup[Set[_]] = new Semigroup[Set[A]] { //error: not found: type A
    def combine(s1: Set[A], s2: Set[A]) = s1.intersect(s2)
  }
}

And if I try using wildcard type parameter throughout the semigroup definition, I get
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Set[_$4] (in scala.collection.immutable)
[error]  required: Set[_$3] (in scala.collection)
[error]     def combine(s1: Set[_], s2: Set[_]) = s1.intersect(s2)
[error]                                                        ^

Is this doable in Scala 2 or 3? If yes, how? If not, why?

Several ways of doing it, but none uses existential types (Set[_]):

type parameter in the implicit:

trait Semigroup[A] {
  def combine(x: A, y: A): A
}

object Semigroup {
  implicit def setIntersectionSG[A]: Semigroup[Set[A]] = new Semigroup[Set[A] {
    def combine(s1: Set[A], s2: Set[A]) = s1.intersect(s2)
  }
}


If it's Cats' Semigroup, then there is also SemigroupK

// If F[_] is used as a type parameter, then it's a type constructor instead
// of existential type, Scala 3 allows making a distinction clearer:
// F[_] (type constructor) vs F[?] (existential type)
trait SemigroupK[F[_]] {

  def combineK[A](x: F[A], y: F[A]): F[A]

  def algebra[A]: Semigroup[F[A]] = combineK(_, _) // Single Abstract Method
}

object SemigroupK {

  implicit val setIntersection: SemigroupK[Set] = new SemigrpupK[Set] {
    def combineK[A](x: Set[A], y: Set[A]): Set[A] = x.intersect(y)
  }
}

SemigroupK is useful for types like collections, which are type-parametric, but which can be combined no matter what kind of a type parameter we apply.
Existential types (Set[_]), have veeeery limited use-cases, and you use them when it's safe to completely forget the type but not for skipping writing it because it's inconvenient.

So in the first case it's one Semigroup instance per type parameter A , and in the second case... it's the same, isn't it? So, again, is it a language or JVM or some other limitation?

You could create 1 instance, save it in private val and cast using asInstanceOf abusing type erasure, but I'd suggest avoiding such tricks before learning how type erasure works and when it matters. Type classes are usually invariant, so one cannot create Semigroup[Set[Nothing]] and upcast on demand.

Could you also add this to your answer? I think it completes the picture
